# i have error | Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE)

Tags: php, mysql, syntax-error, php-5.6

I have an error in my code

> ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) in
>   C:\wamp64\www\cms\include\registor.php on line 32`
>
> line 32

And I can't find a solution.

This my code:

```
<?php
include_once('config.php');
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $username = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
  $email    = $_POST['email'];
  $gender   = $_POST['gender'];
  $about    = strip_tags($_POST['about']);
  $facebook = htmlspecialchars($_POST['facebook']);
  $snapchat = htmlspecialchars($_POST['snapchat']);
  $twitter  = htmlspecialchars($_POST['twitter']);
  $date     = date("Y-m-d");

  if(empty($username)){
    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">الرجاء ادخال اسم المستخدم</div>';
  }elseif(empty($email)){ 
    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">الرجاء ادخال البريد الالكتروني</div>';
  }elseif(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">الرجاء ادخال بريد الكتروني صحيح</div>';
  }elseif(empty($_POST['password'])){
    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">الرجاء ادخال كلمة المرور</div>';
  }elseif(empty($_POST['con_password'])){
    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">الرجاء تاكيد كلمة المرور</div>';
  }elseif($_POST['password'] != $_POST['con_password']){
    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">كلمة المرور غير متطابقة</div>';
  }else{
     $sql_username = mysqli_query ($conn, "SELECT `username` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'");
     $sql_email = mysqli_query ($conn, "SELECT `email` FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '$email'");
     if(mysqli_num_rows($sql_username) > 0){
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">عذراً لكن اسم المستخدم مسجل بالفعل</div>'; 
     }elseif(mysqli_num_rows($sql_email) > 0)
     echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">عذراً لكن الاميل مسجل بالفعل</div>';
     }else{
         if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
              $image = $_FILES['image'];
              $image_name = $image['name'];
              $image_tmp = $image['tmp_name'];
              $image_size = $image['size'];
              $image_error = $image['error'];

              $image_exe = explode('.' , $image_name);
              $image_exe = strtolower(end($image_exe));

              $allowd = array('png','gif','jpg','jpeg');

              if(in_array($image_exe , $allowd)){
                  if($image_error === 0){
                      if($image_size <= 3000000){
                         $new_name = uniqid('user',false) . '.' . $image_exe;
                         $image_dir = '../images/avatar/' . $new_name;
                         $image_db =  'images/avatar/' . $new_name;
                        if(move_uploaded_file($image_tmp , $image_dir)){\
                        $password = md5($_POST['password']);
                        $insert = "INSERT INTO `users` (`username`,
                                                        `email`, 
                                                        `password`, 
                                                        `gender`, 
                                                        `avatar`, 
                                                        `about_user`, 
                                                        `facebook`, 
                                                        `twitter`, 
                                                        `snapchat`, 
                                                        `reg_date`, 
                                                        `role`)
                                                         VALUES
                                                        ('$username',
                                                         '$email',
                                                         '$password',
                                                         '$gender',
                                                         '$image_db',
                                                         '$about',
                                                         '$facebook',
                                                         '$snapchat',
                                                         '$twitter',
                                                         '$date',
                                                         'user')";
                        $insert_sql = mysqli_query($conn , $insert);
                        if(isset($insert_sql)){
                            echo '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">تمت عملية التسجيل بنجاح</div>'
                        }                                                    
                          }else{
                              echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">عذراً حدث خطا اثناء رفع الصورة</div>';
                          }
                      }else{
                          echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">عذراً حجم الصورة اكبر من 2 ميغابايت</div>';
                      }
                  }else{
                        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">عذراً ’ حدث خطاء غير متوقع اثناء رفع الصورة</div>';  
                  }
              }else{
                echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">الرجاء اختيار صوره صالحة</div>';  
              }
          }

     }
}

?>
```

Thank you for your help me

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake. `htmlspecialchars` is **NOT** an escaping method for SQL.

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is largely an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like **SHA1 or MD5**.

Comment: This code is structured in a way that makes it very, very hard to follow. This is primarily because of an excessive level of nesting. It's secondarily caused by a lack of consistent indentation. The best way to solve problems like this is to reduce complexity by shifting code into functions and calling those instead of having wildly nested conditions.

Comment: You're missing a `{` at the end of this line: `}elseif(mysqli_num_rows($sql_email) > 0)`

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an opening curly brace on line #31

`}elseif(mysqli_num_rows($sql_email) > 0)`

needs to be

`}elseif(mysqli_num_rows($sql_email) > 0) {`

Please see the comments; @tadman brings up great points.